# Invalid URL pattern using Django with Mezzanine

Tags: django, mezzanine

I'm relatively new using Mezzanine and Django.  But I run the manage.py with runserver as a parameter and I get the following error.

```
ERRORS:
?: (urls.E004) Your URL pattern (u'^', (<module 'mezzanine.urls' from       
'C:\Users\khirst\InovaSupportSiteIsolated\lib\site-packages\mezzanine\urls.py'>, None, Non
e)) is invalid. Ensure that urlpatterns is a list of url() instances.
    HINT: Try using url() instead of a tuple.
```

I browsed through Mezzanine's urls.py,  and it seems to be properly updated for the new urlpatterns standards.  I am using Django 1.10.0, and Mezzanine 4.2.2.

There are several lines that use

```
urlpatterns += [url("^", include("..") ..
```

of some sort.  I am guessing that 
means that for every url, add the following module as a possible match.  It seems that Django doesn't like one of these.  I can't find any help with this on Mezzanine's site or otherwise.  Supposedly this version of Mezzanine and Django are supposed to be compatible.  Has anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I blamed mezzanine, but it was our fault in our base module.

We had a tuple in our urls file.

```
("^", include("mezzanine.urls"))
```

That needed to be

```
url("^", include("mezzanine.urls"))
```

But Django was complaining as if it was in mezzanine's code.